# Best Practices to Save Credit

Tags: azure

I noticed that my credit goes down even if I have all my virtual machines stopped and deallocated. What else can I do to save credits, when I'm not using it? I currently have some VMs, 1 cloud service, 1 storage, and 1 network, nothing else.

Comment: I would recommend checking the subscription usage by going to https://account.windowsazure.com. That should tell you which component is actually consuming some of your credits.

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cloud-services/ *If my deployed instance is in the "stopped" state, do I still get billed?
Yes, a stopped instance still occupies the compute resource that powers the instance, and therefore you still get billed. In order to stop billing, you need to delete your deployment.* Although I believe MSDN subscription-based Azure subscriptions are exempt from this rule.

Comment: @ta.speot.is ... this is true but the question is if the cloud service mentioned by Ricardo is just the shell cloud service which gets created when you create a VM to get a cloudapp.net DNS name or is it an actual Cloud Service with some deployed code.

Comment: It is a MSDN subscription. Why on Earth was I downvoted for asking this?

Comment: Thanks for the info, ta.speot.is and Gaurav Mantri!